# Virtual Functions Doubts

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have this simple code to test VF

```
class A
{
public:
virtual const char Get (){return 'A';}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
const char Get (){return 'B';}
};

class C : public B
{
public:
const char Get (){return 'C';}
};

class D : public C
{
public:
const char Get (){return 'D';}
};
```

inside main ()

```
D dD;
std::cout<<dD.Get()<<std::endl; //prints D

A & rA = dD;
std::cout<<rA.Get()<<std::endl;//prints D

C cC;

A & rA2 = cC;
std::cout<<rA2.Get()<<std::endl; //print C

B & rB = dD;
std::cout<<rB.Get()<<std::endl;
/*????? it prints D, shouldn't it print B ?????*/
```

rB points to address dD, rB will only refer to the object (B and A) of the dD object (won't see C&D).

When rB.Get () is called, shouldn't it goes to the most derived function which is in B, not in A and execute it?

Comment: Why do you think the most derived object is in B? rB is a reference to a B but the most derived is a D.  See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual

Comment: well correct me if I am wrong, but I thought in the case of rB it refers to the A&B part of object dD, and in that context when rB.Get() is called, the compiler will see the most derived Get () in A & B and it is B::Get()

Comment: @Adam: yes, you are wrong. `rB` is a reference to a `D` object. The whole point of `virtual` functions is that the static type can be a base while the dynamic type is a derived and for `virtual` function version of the most derived dynamic type is called.

Comment: - if A::Get () is not virtual

- `std::cout<<rB.Get() is executed

- compiler will seek the most derived Get() in A & B and execute, which is B::Get() not A::Get ()

- why does it happen if A::Get() is not virtual, but if it is, compiler will see A::Get() not B::Get()

Comment: Perhaps you are confused by the lack of `virtual` in the Get() methods in B, C, and D. They are all virtual. Labeling them virtual or not makes no difference since their virtualness is set by the base class.

Comment: you are right @doug, I was confused with the virtual, now it makes much more sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When a function is virtual in a class `Base` it's virtual in all derived classes, classes derived from derived classes, and so on, regardless of the use or not of the word `virtual` in the derived classes.

In your case this means that `Get` is virtual in all your classes `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Hence the cases `rA` and `rB` are examples of the same kind of situation.

The return type can vary slightly: a raw reference or pointer as return type can be specialized in a derived class. Since it then varies in specificity in the same direction as the containing class it's called a covariant return type. C++ does not, however, support variance of arguments.

Comment: yes virtual Base will make a derived functions virtual too, that part confused me, but now I understood it. Thank you